# Why AdMob always shows me Request Error: No ad to show. in iOS

Tags: ios, ads, admob

I updated to latest sdk,
Also confirmed multiple time app id and interestial ad unit id, all is fine, but still not getting ads and getting error like this.

I am using this code:

```
    func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
    let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: APPWSConstant.InterstitialAd_Unit_Id)
    interstitial.delegate = self
    let request : GADRequest = GADRequest()
    interstitial.load(request)
    return interstitial
}
```

But, for all cases it calls failure methods and show no ads available.
interstitial:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:

Request Error: No ad to show.

Comment: You try with test Ad Unit ID of Google. If Ads is displayed with test Ad Unit ID then your code is OK. Maybe you need to wait a few hours after you create new Ads ID

Comment: I get this error too, it is on both of open ad and interstitial ad with test ad unit id. And I don't change any code of MobAds, which works fine before. It seems something happened on google's ad network, I will get to sleep and have another try tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

No problem with ad integration and your AD UNIT ID. Main reasons for

> Request Error: No ad to show

are :

1. Sometimes the Ad Unit ID starts delivering ads immediately, and sometimes the Ad Unit ID can take a few hours before delivering ads. There is no official AdMob documentation stating the activation time.
2. Experiencing this on iOS 10 when Limit Ad Tracking (in Settings/Privacy/Advertising) is on.

Hope This will Help you.

Happy Coding :)